# IQueryable exclude column duplicates but keep all nulls

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Hi I'm building up query to fetch products from database, first I dynamically sort it, then I need to retrieve products based on their `ProductGroupId` property which needs to exclude duplicates and then I page it. Problem is that I don't know how to properly exclude duplicates while keeping nulls and sorting intact.

---

#### Database products

```
Id     ProductGroupId
-------------
1      null
2      null
3      2
4      1
5      2
6      null
7      1
8      null
```

Query should return 6 records in total excluding products 5 and 7 because their ProductGroupId marks them as duplicates.

---

```
query = query.OrderBy(input.Sorting);

if (input.Sorting != "Price")
{        
    query = // query.GroupBy or something ... ?
}

query = ApplyPaging(query, input);

var entities = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my requirements was to avoid premature `ToList()` for performance reasons. I've achieved the required filtering using `Union`, but `Concat` would work as well.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.ProductGroupId == null)
            .Union(query.Where(x => x.ProductGroupId != null).GroupBy(x => x.ProductGroupId).Select(x => x.First()));
```

---

It's important to note, there is currently pitfall in EntityFrameworkCore where certain Concat/Union scenarios lead to **ArgumentNullException** tracked by [Issue #11007](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11007)

If chain were to be reversed, exception would be thrown

```
query = query.Where(x => x.ProductGroupId != null).GroupBy(x => x.ProductGroupId).Select(x => x.First())
            .Union(query.Where(x => x.ProductGroupId == null));
```